# How to build 'migrations' or similar functionalities for modules in FuelPHP

Tags: php, module, migration, fuelphp

FulePHP is a HMVC framework that allows 'modules' to have their own MVC structure. The framework also provides a handy tool called 'migration', that resolves database & code version conflicts (during development) in an elegant way.

However, the migration tool is app-wise. Management of package DB Schemae & Fixtures is not supported.

I came up with these alternative solutions :

1. Build and test each modules with it's dependency as a FuelPHP project, so that 'migrations' can be used exclusively. Requires a whole lot of configurations, with a strict and environment (dev/production) branch policy.
2. Scan and link files in 'APPPATH/modules/[mod_name]/migrations' to 'migrations' after updating or installing a modules.
3. The legacy way: Maintain sql files for DB schema & fixture by hand, loaded if tables were not found at runtime.

Combining solution 1 and 2 seems reasonable, but would take a great amount of work. Is there some elegant way to do so, or to port migration support to modules?

Thanks in advance.

** edited, 'modules' should be where I'm looking for, not 'packages'

In short, I'd like to have my module directory look like:

- classes

  - controller
  - model
  - view
- config
- *migrations*
- lang
- views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations in packages are already supported.

Comment: I've edited my question a bit to make it would be clearer. There are _find_app(), _find_module(), and _find_package() in core/clases/migrate.php, so I'll check why my codes didn't run as expected. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is 'oil refine migrate:help' to look up options, use --modules (-m), --packages (-p), or --all to invoke such behavior.